# Use a picture as signature in Mac OS X Mail

Tags: mac, email, email-signature

I would like to add a default signature in Mac OS X Maill application (Snow Leopard), where the signature is a PNG or JPG or some other picture. How can this be done? I did not find any option for this.

Comment: Just... don't...

Comment: @Daniel I might even speculate that they didn't add this option on purpose

Comment: [The third comment on this post might be related](http://superuser.com/questions/259918/in-2011-what-are-the-reasons-to-stick-with-plain-text-mails/259928#259928).

Comment: I often receive emails through the Exchange Server at work with picture signatures and the Postini spam filter stops them from reaching my inbox every time. Just wanted to give you a heads up that there might be unintended consequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Preferences (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> or "Mail" in menu bar), go to "Signatures", select one of your existing signatures (or add a new one with <kbd>+</kbd>) and simply **drag and drop** an image into the editing window:

[image: Screenshot Mail.app]

Comment: thanks a lot! the only thing; If i sent an email to some gmail account, the signature appears as attachment, is it normal or can it be changed?